# Return only one value by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to return only the object on which we clicked, not the entire collection?

```
 $('[id^=opener]').click(function() {
     document.write($('[id^=opener]').find(this));
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `$(this)`:

```
 $('[id^=opener]').click(function() {
     console.log($(this)); // this refers the target you clicked.
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use :

```
 $('[id^=opener]').click(function() {
     console.log(this);
    event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

OR

```
$('[id^=opener]').click(function(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: He doesn't pass an event parameter

Comment: It return 4 same object:                                       Object { 0=a#opener1, context=a#opener1, length=1, more...}
list# (line 356)
Object { 0=a#opener1, context=a#opener1, length=1, more...}
list# (line 479)
Object { 0=a#opener1, context=a#opener1, length=1, more...}
list# (line 602)
Object { 0=a#opener1, context=a#opener1, length=1, more...}
list# (line 725)

Comment: Try:  console.log($(this).get(0));

Comment: console.log($(this).get(0)); It return: <a id="opener1" title="Give book" href="#">
list# (line 354)
<a id="opener1" title="Give book" href="#">
list# (line 476)
<a id="opener1" title="Give book" href="#">
list# (line 598)
<a id="opener1" title="Give book" href="#">
list# (line 720)